# Not reading from dimens specific resolution folder

Tags: android

I have an values-xhdpi folder with dimens.xml file. Now I wish to do specific dimens for Nexus 4, so I have created values-xhdpi-1280x768 folder and I can see the changes in the graphic layout, but when I run the app on the device I can see it still reads from values-xhdpi folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!
Needed to use values-xhdpi-1184x768 because buttons bar is 96px. 
Thank you ME!